# Import module from root path in TypeScript with intellij-idea

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, intellij-idea

i know this topic is very much asked
i try read it but still fail

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "locale": "zh-TW",
    "pretty": true,
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "/root/src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "newLine": "lf"
  }
}
```

this is my directory structure

```
node_modules
src
  gw2taco
    index
test
  r
```

r.ts (all fail)

- import 'src/gw2taco'; console.log(7777);
- import '/src/gw2taco'; console.log(7777);

im use intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

#### For the import

Given this directory structure:

```
node_modules
src
  gw2taco
    index.ts
test
  r.ts
```

One option for the import in `r.ts` is this:

```
import "../src/gw2taco";
```

#### For the tsconfig.json

- Delete the `baseUrl`, `rootDir`, and `paths` entries.
- Put the `include` and `exclude` properties outside of the `compilerOptions`.
- Add your test directory to the `include`.
- Capitalize the `newLine` property to `LF`.

The file result looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "locale": "zh-TW",
    "pretty": true,
    "newLine": "LF"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

#### All together in VSCode

[image]

Comment: What if I want to import a file in root level from a file that is deep within another folder ?